# how to get a CSSStyleSheet object from a <style>

Tags: css, stylesheet

One < style > corresponding one CSSStyleSheet object (in document.styleSheets), but how to find it, such as the CSSStyleSheet object corresponding < style id="-yCoder-styles" >...< /style>

```
console.log(document.styleSheets.length);

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.title = "-yCoder-styles";
style.type= 'text/css';
style.id = "-yCoder-styles";
document.head.appendChild(style);

//how to get the corresponding CSSStyleSheet instance from document.styleSheets

console.log(document.styleSheets.length);

var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
console.log(styleSheet.title == style.title);
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/MKu5u/

Comment: my code is working because I know the style is the last one, but if I only know the <style> id, how can I find the corresponding CSSStyleSheet object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, you should be able to get your associated CSSStyleSheet with:

```
var styleSheet = style.sheet
```

This will only work **after** the `<style>` element has been appended to the document.

Not exceptionally well documented and very difficult to find by poking around in console.

Comment: It's documented on MDN here: ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement ) and on MSDN here ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974766(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: I meant that the fact that the `<style>` element had to be appended first was not particularly well-documented. I'll try to be more clear in the future :-)