# CSSStyleSheet class disappears when parsing an SVG string

Tags: css, xml, svg, xml-parsing

**Example:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1u987sh/)

I have an **svg** image with a **style** element

```
<svg ...>
  <style>
    ...
  </style>
  ...
</svg>
```

If I embed the svg onto an empty HTML document, these two blocks of code result in a difference that I didn't expect.

block #1

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg")
```

block #2

```js
let s = new XMLSerializer();
let p = new DOMParser();
let svg = p.parseFromString(s.serializeToString(document.querySelector("svg")), "image/svg+xml").documentElement;
```

These two blocks produce a difference in regards to the `<style>` child (.children[0] here). The [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/CSSStyleSheet) is normally found on the "sheet" property on the `<style>` child:

```js
svg.children[0].sheet
```

- in block #1, the "sheet" property is available.
- in block #2, it's **null**.

why is this? Am I doing something wrong in block #2? The `<style>` child exists in both cases, it just isn't recognized as a CSSStyleSheet in block #2.

---

The purpose of all of this is that I am building an SVG parser, so I need to be able to load files as strings and parse them.

workaround?: I can get the innerHTML of the `<style>` element in both cases, but [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/CSSStyleSheet) doesn't have a simple constructor where I can pass in the entire string; that would be nice, I could construct a new CSSStyleSheet. I can create a CSSStyleSheet and add rules individually, but I think I need to parse CSS, which sounds difficult.

I just want the benefit of the [CSSRuleList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList). being able to iterate over that is super helpful.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>` also contains version, viewBox

Comment: @RobertLongson sure thing https://jsfiddle.net/f1u987sh/

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. it's not well documented

> A `<style>` element must be a child of the HTMLDocument (not XMLDocument, nor parent-less) for the "sheet" property to exist and be of type CSSStyleSheet.

this was previously uncovered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661839/1956418).

---

#### solution (summary)

append the `<style>` element to the window.document.body, then access "sheet" property.

#### solution (detail)

1. get the **root parent node** of the `<style>` element (loop `.parentNode` until at root).
2. check the type of root with `root.constructor === window.HTMLDocument`.

*(you can't test against null because XMLDocument will not generate a "sheet" property)*

if #2 is true, "sheet" property will exist. if false, continue:

3. append the `<style>` to document.body. (or the `<svg>` if it contains the style. both work)
4. the sheet property now exists. do whatever you need with it.
5. remove `<style>` from document.body.